# Change Chrome installation folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows, google-chrome

How can I change the Chrome installation folder when I install it? It gives no option to do so.

Answer (score 2):

For those who may still be out there attempting to find a solution.  Google offers an Enterprise version of the installer.  It's a .msi installer but its default installation directory is C:\program files\google  instead of the typical c:\user\user\appdata\local\google

Comment: Link: https://www.google.be/work/chrome/browser/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. This was once possible with google pack, which is now dead software.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this, but I think it may be possible using the [MSI installer](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?msi=true). Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841965/1364854) would seem to indicate that it would work with something like

`msiexec /i "chrome.msi" TARGETDIR="C:\chrome" /qb`

with the appropriate paths, of course.

Answer (score 0):

http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable

This or a symbolic link is the only way I see.

Unless you're able to just move the installation directory as you please after the installation, and Chrome is smart enough to adjust? Might want to try that.