# Chrome works only outside of sandbox?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, virus, malware

I have been trying to solve this problem for a long time. I have been using Chrome for more than 4 years, it is the best browser for me.

Suddenly, Chrome stopped working. I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it more than 20 times, but it's still not working. By not working I mean **I can't open pages, I can't open settings, I can't open plugin's, etc.**

I have searched a lot on the Internet and I have installed many programs to remove trojans, worms, malware. But Chrome is still only working outside of sandbox.

**From the Run prompt;**

- This works: **chrome --no-sandbox**
- Doesn't work: **chrome**

My operating system is Windows 7 64-bit.

**Update 1**

Screenshot per user request.

[image: chrome blank window]

**Update 2**

When I open the Task Manager in Chrome, I see something called GigaAuthExtension. I didn't install this. Could this be the problem?

[image: chrome task manager]

**Update 3**

I found that I am unable to start Google Services on Windows.

#### Update 4

When I run chrome, I noticed this strange process:
`conhost.exe` and the path of it starts with `??`. I just see it when I run chrome the first time after restarting windows

is this a maleware?

#### Update 4

When I open a chrome page, I found these processes

#### Update 5

I found that I have a process named `csrss.exe`, I read that this could be either a system process or a maleware with the same system process name. I tried to right click on it and go to location, but no location open. I mean nothing opened. is that the problem?

Comment: Show the screenshot of the issue. For temporary solution you can use [portable chrome](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable).

Comment: @crazypotato I updated my question with a screenshot, the page keeps like this forever

Comment: @crazypotato please if you need more information tell me

Comment: What happens when you click on “Apps”?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Have you used Chrome Sync to back up your data (extensions, saved passwords, history, bookmarks, etc.)?

Comment: @DanielB when I click on `apps`, the url becomes this `chrome://apps/` but it never open the app page, i mean chrome keep trying to open it but it never sucess

Comment: @Vinayak yes i am already using chrome sync

Comment: Okay, in that case, I'd suggest you try deleting this folder: `%appdata%\..\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`. Make sure Google Chrome is't running when you delete the folder.

Comment: @Vinayak delete the `default` folder or delete **al the content** inside it?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: The `Default` folder. That's the [user data folder](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory).

Comment: @Vinayak I deleted the `default` folder, and then opened chrome, but unfortunately nothing change, the problem keeps as it was, the only change is that chrome this time asked me if I want it to be my default browser. :( appreciate if you can help me more please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17003/discussion-between-vinayak-and-marco-dinatsoli).

Comment: Try install Chrome in different location. [People says](http://superuser.com/a/674620/348563) if install [Business version](http://www.google.com/chrome/business/browser/admin/) default path will be `C:\program files\`

Comment: @crazypotato what is the difference between this business version and the normal version and should I uninstall my current damaged version before installing your new business version?

Comment: @Vinayak I updated the question could you check please?

Comment: @crazypotato I updated the question, could you check please?

Comment: @Vinayak Hi man, unfortunately, the VMP didn't help me and I noticed that google services are not able to start. any advice please?

Comment: I think you meant, "VPN". And I'm sorry but I am out of ideas.

Comment: @Vinayak yes sorry I meant VPN, I appreciate your efforts

Comment: "Chrome just works with no sandbox options". To me, this sounds like Chrome is working. How is the sandbox feature relevant for the question? Can you please clarify? I have left a "please clarify" note inside square brackets above for you to fill in. I didn't know if I should remove it or not. Is your computer in fact infected? If the rest of the system is not infected, then my guess is that the sandboxing feature of Chrome just saved your ass. You can forget about Chrome if your system is infected. In which case you have a much bigger problem.

Comment: @sammyg my system is 100% not infected because I have made a lot a lot of scans and windows is always updated, the problem just happens with chrome, i have all the other programs like visual studio, ecipse, couchbase, sql server, oracle apache xampp and vmware working perfectly. the problem with sand box is that chrome states that working with sand box is not safe and I need to run chrome as normal not with sand box because when i remove the sand box nothing in chrome works not even the settings nor the extension pages

Comment: Wow! That's a lot of software for one man to handle! :) However, none of those is a security software. Running Eclipse alongside Visual Studio won't help you remove viruses. I just realized that this is a two day old question, I thought it was a new one. Are you still working on this? I think I understand what you are saying about the sandbox now. But that basically means that your computer has been compromised. Some malware in your system is preventing Chrome from starting in sandbox mode.

Comment: @sammyg no you understand me wronge, I can open chrome **just** with no sandbox mode, but If I removed that open chrome will open but I won't be able to load any page , i can't even load the settings page. plus, i have scan the pc hundred of times using up to date softwares. I even bought the key for malewarebytes, and that apps states that my system is clear. now I found this page http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/definitions/adl.aspx i don't now if it will work for me.

Comment: You need to re-phrase "chrome states that working with sand box is not safe" to "chrome states that working _without_ sand box is not safe". Also re-phrase "I need to run chrome as normal not with sand box" to "I need to run chrome as normal not without sand box". Normal mode is WITH sandbox! Not without! But of course, the malware won't let you do that. It won't let you run Chrome in sandbox mode. It will only run in the ab-normal non-sandbox mode.

Comment: @sammyg yes you right i should update the question, could you do that for me please? my english is bad. i guess you can explain it better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17064/discussion-between-sammyg-and-marco-dinatsoli).

Comment: Something to check: Right-click on the Chrome icon and check if in Properties/Compatibility it is running in Windows XP mode, and if it is then uncheck the checkbox and press OK.

Comment: @harrymc that option was not checked

Comment: @Vinayak I updated my question, could you check please?

Comment: I just updated my question guys, could you check please?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: That still doesn't help. Sorry. `csrss.exe` is a valid process. So is `conhost.exe`. And I'm pretty sure that it didn't just start with only the `\??\ ` parameter, but with something like `\??\C:\WINDOWS\System32\conhost.exe...` which is normal I guess.

Comment: Does this happen when running Chrome with (1) the `--disable-extensions` command-line option, and (2) in an incognito window?

Comment: @harrymc yes the problem hasspens with the two options you said

Comment: and when I open any chrome page, I found 4 chrome process in task manager. is that normal?

Comment: Weird. I suggest to completely uninstall Chrome, as [described here](http://www.mytechguide.org/444/how-to-manually-uninstall-google-chrome/), reboot, then reinstall.

Comment: @harrymc though I already tried that using `redo ` application, but I will do that again and update you

Comment: @harrymc I can't try your solution, it involues runs registery script which may be harmful to my computer

Comment: I suggest then to remove Chrome using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html), This should totally delete it without a registry script. Just verify that the folder ` %APPDATA%\Google\Chrome` is really gone.

Comment: @harrymc I did that before my friend. and then re installed chrome but the problem keeps, you are welcome to access my laptop remotely to check if you want

Comment: One more try: start Chrome, switch from regular view to presentation view, access the settings, then advanced settings, scroll down to "System" and uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available" and restart chrome.

Comment: @harrymc I uncheck the `use hardware...` and the problem keeps. I didn't understand where to find the `presentation view` you talked about

Comment: If you found the setting, then no more is required. Last try: Boot Windows in [Safe Mode with Networking](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7) and check if the problem is still there. Question: What happens if you resize Chrome while the blank page is displayed?

Comment: @harrymc I found the settings using `-no-sandbox` option ofc. I am not able to load any pages or setttings or extensions without that option. I will test the resize and update you

Comment: @harrymc resizing doesn't change anything. the problem keeps. I will go to safe mode with networking and test again because I already tested that too :(

Comment: @harrymc one last thing before safe mode please. when I run chrome I got 4 process for it in the task manager, is that normal?

Comment: See this: [Why Does Chrome Have So Many Open Processes?](http://www.howtogeek.com/124218/why-does-chrome-have-so-many-open-processes/).

Comment: @harrymc I tried with safe mode and networking and the problem keeps, i uninstalled chrome now and I am disappointed

Comment: I have summarized our work as an answer below.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli this is not a solution, but could you try installing an [older version of Google Chrome](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-chrome/) and see if that works, so we know if this problem has something to do with Chrome or your computer.

Comment: @Vinayak the same current version was working with me, any way I will download an older version and install it and update you

Comment: @Vinayak I will download this version `Google Chrome 26.0.1410.5 Dev`

Comment: @Vinayak MY HERO MY HERO MY HERO MY HERO MY HERO MY HERO . You are the God man . Installing an older version SOLVED THE PROBLEM, SOLVED THE PROBLEM hahahha I am happy so happy sooooooooo happy I like you , write an answer to accept it please quickly

Comment: It's not really a solution though. However, I'll add an answer nevertheless. If this is a bug, Google might fix it in later versions. Make sure you don't have automatic updates enabled until then.

Comment: @Vinayak the problem that when I tried to go to `about` page to update my chrome, I got `Update failed (error: 3)An error occurred while checking for updates: Update check failed to start (error code 3: 0x80040154).` and the google update service in windows is not able to start

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: You must open the `chrome://conflicts` page using the latest (non-functioning) version of Google Chrome. Also you don't have to post the entire output of the conflicts page. Just let us know if you see a `Modules (number) - No conflicts detected` message at the top or not.

Comment: I had the same problem with 64-bit chrome. I had installed 32-bit version and it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** This is not a permanent solution.

You can try installing an [older version of Google Chrome](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-chrome/) and see if that works.

If this problem is introduced by a new version of Google Chrome, then it could mean there's a software conflict with something on your computer.

It might even help to read the changelogs and see what was introduced/removed/modified between the last working version of Google Chrome and the one after it. That might help pinpoint the problem.

As @harrymc suggested, you should try filing a bug report. You can do that from Chrome itself:
[image: Chrome button] → Help → Report and Issue. Or use the shortcut combination, <kbd>LAlt</kbd>+<kbd>LShift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

EDIT: It looks like this is a [known issue](https://support.google.com/chrome/known-issues/15036?hl=en). It seems very likely that the problem might be related to old software causing conflicts on your computer (as previously suggested)

You can check if a software conflict is present by visiting this page: `chrome://conflicts`
If you see outdated software listed there, you should update them and hopefully, that'll fix the problem.

Comment: many thanks for the great efforts. just one thing please, I am using now version 26, and the last version is 37, so where can I find the version 36?

Comment: You can get older versions of Google Chrome [here as well](http://filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/history).

Comment: I just reported the bug and I mentioned to this question in the bug

Comment: Nevermind. I think I found the problem. I'll edit my answer soon.

Comment: I already tried the conflicts page yesterday, I will try it now and update you with the list. plus I had babylon app which confluicts with chrome and I un installed it yesterday

Comment: I got `Modules (110) - No conflicts detected`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Did you try this with the latest (non-functioning) version of Google Chrome?

Comment: yes yesterday and I found the long list(which I removed from the question) but I dont' remember that I found the `Modules (110) - No conflicts detected` message. do you want me to re install that lastest version and check ?

Comment: Please do. If you see that you find any conflicts listed, uninstall/upgrade the relevant software and try re-starting Google Chrome.

Comment: the same there is no conflicts detected with the last version of chrome.

Comment: I noticed that my chrome version now is 37 and the lastest is 39  though I downloaded chrome from the offical page,

Comment: Version 37 is the latest stable release. Version 39 is a developer build.

Comment: If you don't see any conflicts with the latest (stable) version of Chrome, I guess what you could do is submit a bug report and/or ask the question on [Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Something on your computer is conflicting with Chrome. As it also happens in Safe Mode
with Network, this isn't software and has rather something to do with your hardware or display driver or Windows itself.

Try updating your display driver, preferably getting it from the manufacturer's website.
If one doesn't exist, at least check if Windows Update has such a driver as an optional
update. If you find such an update but it doesn't help, try toggling
"Use hardware acceleration when available"
in Chrome's settings to on or off, restarting Chrome each time.

It could also be a corruption in Windows, but this is not reason enough to go to the trouble of reinstalling Windows. You could check this possibility by following this article
describing [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html), which
scans the integrity of all protected Windows 7 system files and replaces incorrect corrupted, changed/modified, or damaged versions with the correct versions if possible.

If everything fails, in my opinion Firefox is a very capable browser
(and less buggy than Chrome).

Comment: I just found this chrome removal tool officially by google https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6086368?hl=en&ref_topic=3421433 and I run it and it tells me that there is no error in my computer, I am confused about your talking about display driver, why that could be the problem:?

Comment: The display driver might be involved because this is a display problem, where Chrome might be trying to use the driver cleverly to display the page faster. When you are advised to turn off hardware acceleration, the hardware in question is the video card, and the acceleration is using it in a sophisticated way. However, hardware acceleration might not be the only optimization that Chrome is attempting, unsuccessfully in your case. If you are in doubt where to find the video driver, let me know the exact make of your video card.

Comment: I am using invedia for my display card and i updated it using windows update and the problem keeps

Comment: `Vinayak` solved my problem :)

Comment: You mean NVIDIA? Try their [Automatically find drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) page (requires Java or Internet Explorer). Please note that going back to an older Chrome version is not a solution, since (1) Using an old version is a security risk, and (2) Chrome auto-updates its version so this will not hold for too long. It's possible to block the auto-update, but is really not recommended. I suggest filing a bug report with the Chrome developers and using another browser in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem before. I kept trying for 4 months to solve it.
I thought that the problem could have happened because of a maleware, span or something.

I also thought that the graphic driver is not compatible with Chrome.

**Finally**
The solution was to change the *compatibility* of Chrome to `Windows Vista`.

1. Right click on chrome icon.
2. Go to *properties*.
3. Open *Compatibility* tab.
4. Check the *Run this program in compatibility mode for* check box.
5. Select **Windows Vista**.
6. Click *Apply* and *OK*.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: This approach was what worked for me.  On Win 10 I started to suddenly get this error.  Setting compatibility to Windows 7 did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue, Windows 8.1 64-bit. I Had just installed "Intel Rapid Storage Technology" -- both the app and the drivers. Took me quite a bit of troubleshooting to pin it down. Ended up removing it because it was the only thing I'd changed since chrome stopped working.

Rebooted, and Tada, everything works. I should note, I could get chrome to work with "--no-sandbox" as well as running the Chrome Beta.

Hopefully this helps someone else. Uninstall Intel Rapid Storage Technology.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the perfect solution you might be wishing for, but it may just work as a temporary fix until you can get to the bottom of this.

1. Get [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) and install it.
2. Use Sandboxie to create a new sandbox.
3. Run Chrome outside of its sandbox with the option `--no-sandbox` but
   inside the sandbox you created with Sandboxie.

The benefit of this is that you can continue using Chrome, while Sandboxie will provide the system protection by the means of sandboxing technology you are used to.

See this YouTube video for an overview of how Sandboxie works: http://youtu.be/iVdY2cMTjPA

Comment: I updated the question, could you check please?

Comment: `Vinayak` solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got exact the same problem as you Marco,  it randomly appeared and I can only run Chrome(public, beta and canary) in **--no-sandbox** mode.

I had a conversation on Twitter with Paul Kinlan from the Google Chrome Developer Team https://twitter.com/0x1AD2/status/529563795119947776 but he couldn't help me out(yet).

<strike>Now I'm trying to run the **sfc /scannow** command and if that results in nothing I'll try the [Software Removal Tool](https://www.google.com/chrome/srt/) or [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/)</strike>

I tried running the scan but without results also the removal tool couldn't find anything. The only option I've left is Sandboxie.

*If I come across a solution I'll update my post.*

Comment: thanks for the asnewr, yes please if you have any update tell us, since i still have that fu..king prolbme

Comment: I still have the same problems, running version 39.0.2171.71 now :\  I think it has something to do with my Windows configuration because it's working at home and there I'm running a different version. What kind of OS do you use.

Comment: now i installed the latest version and now unfortunately, even with --no-sandbox option, Chrome is not working :( i am gonna loose my mine

Answer (score 0):

Check if chrome is running on compatibility mode. This happens when chrome is running with compatibility for windows xp. Try this:
Right click on chrome > Properties > Compatibility.
Disable compatibility mode.
Relaunch chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Here are five different solutions. I suggest trying them down in the order they are listed. I have myself encountered this problem twice both resulting from different reasons.

1. Right click on the Chrome icon and go to *Properties*. Select the *Compatibility* tab and uncheck *Run this program in compatibility mode for:* option. (This may arise when Chrome updates on windows and resets to some default compatibility mode).
2. Go to `C:\Users\"Your Username"\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage` and delete all data. (You may have to unhide hidden files from folder options).
3. Download an anti-malware software like *Malwarebytes* or whatever suits you and scan your system. Some malware might be causing a problem.
4. Try un-installing and re-installing Chrome.
5. If none of the above work, try reverting to an older version of Google Chrome, for some compatibility issues between your system and a new version of Chrome might be preventing it from functioning normally.